# passing decimals to REST API from multilingual frontend

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a REST API in .Net Core 3 and front end in Angular 8. My front is a multilingual admin panel where I need to configure price for a product. The issue is I am not able receive price with decimal values.

My default culture of .NET Core API is "en-US" but my client is using "nl-NL" from front end. As you know Netherland they use "," instead of "." for decimal points therefore I am not getting price in my submitted model. Here are code snippets;

**REST API**

*Entity*

```
public class Product{
  public Guid Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public decimal Price {get;set;}
}
```

*Controller Method*

```
[HttpPost]
public Task<IActionResult> SaveProduct([FromForm]Product model){
  ....code to save the product....
}
```

*Stratup.cs*

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                new CultureInfo("de"),
                new CultureInfo("fr"),
                new CultureInfo("sv")
            };
            options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>()
            {
                new AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider()
            };
            options.FallBackToParentCultures = true;
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
```

I tried setting Requestdefault culture to "nl" but then "en" values doesn't work. Can any one please help me how to pass decimal points from multilingual frontend to a REST API.

Thanks.

Comment: You do know that getting the price from the URL is a surefire way to have this abused? Like people entering a price of 0.01?

Comment: @Christopher I am posting value from strictly typed values in number format and number format is different in different culture which means 0.01 is correct value for a product price as well 0,01. It is due to culture variation

Comment: Where are you retrieving the price from? Based on the tags, I am assuming `SaveProduct` is a REST API call and you're receiving `application/json`? If that's the case, you should modify the Angular front-end code to submit a number. The internal representation of the value (i.e, the cost) can be different from the external representation (i.e, how it is displayed to the user). You should add your Angular form code to this question, it would help out greatly.

Comment: yes {SaveProduct} is a REST API call but I am not passing json data I am submitting formdata. If I need to fix data before submitting in angular, I have to do it in each HttpPost request. Which I do not want. This is more of C# help request rather angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, it appears that your problem is that your front-end code is submitting the price with a comma on it. This can only be possible if you are sending a string representation of the price to the server, rather than a numeric one.

You should modify your front end code to always store and transmit the price value as a `number`. You can control how a price is displayed to a user in strings using `Intl.NumberFormat()`.

As the user has to enter a price, you're probably using a `<input type=text />` tag to capture the cost of the product. Since we want users to be able to enter commas here, we can't use `<input type=number />` - instead, we can simply modify the value we get from this input tag on the client side by replacing occurences of commas in the string with a period - `amount.replace(',', '.')` - and then attempting to parse the number from the string - `parseInt(amount, 10)`.

If `parseInt` returns `NaN`, you should display a validation error to the user.

Comment: As I mentioned that the frontend is multilingual so the input price can be in both formats 0.01 or 0,01 and both are correct in respective cultures. I am using kendoNuemricText box to get the decimal values based on specified culture. Frontend is correct in my case

Comment: The input price may very well be 0.01 or 0,01, but you should convert that price (which is likely a string) to a number before you send it to the backend. As I mentioned in the comments, the underlying value (in this case, the number 0.01) can be used while still displaying a different representation (in this case, 0,01) to the user. It's not that the frontend is incorrect, it's that you're sending a string from the client to the server instead of a number.

Comment: This solves the problem you mentioned earlier about having to do it in each request - You don't. *always* store the underlying value by baking this conversion to and from commas inside your input controls. It is the wrong place to fix this in the server side IMO. How the data is displayed is *solely* a concern for the view layer (Angular), *not* the logic layer.

Comment: It is correct that representation can be different then the under laying data-type. But if I change default culture to "nl-NL" in C# it accepts 0,01 value but not 0.01 value. Then If I have to manage price conversion on client side then I have to manage datetime conversion as well... There must be a way to handle it in C#

Comment: @Riy: Does the frontend have a Parse() function? Because then you could parse, then print back in a known Culture. Or use the numerical value.

Comment: @Christopher yes, it has but then I need to parse every single request before it post. I know, I can create one single input configuration to fix that at frontend but I am hopping that C# can have some solution e.g. some middleware to inject and parse required piece of data

Comment: "yes, it has but then I need to parse every single request before it post." then that is the simplest and most reliable solution! Do not make the mistake of trying to Optimize Speed before there is a problem: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ (you can skip 1) It working *at all* while Multilingual is so important, there likely is no equivalent solution.

Comment: @Riy why do you want a more complicated fix (middleware) than a simpler one (frontend change)?

Comment: @DanPantry it is because, API needs to be available to clients so that they can create their own UIs. I can fix in UI but to tell the clients that their developer has to fix their UIs will create negative impact. :(

Comment: What if the client wants to display data in their own format independent of the language they request it in? For example, what if I - based in Ireland - want to request a date in the American format MM-DD-YYYY? Do I have to change my request to request en-US instead of en-UK? Don't make assumptions like this. Leave it to the view layer to display how data is rendered. In this case, that's the client. **not the server side**. The server should display the data in a localisation neutral way.

Comment: That is the case here because you are designing an *API* and APIs should not have data served in the most convenient format for humans, but in the most convenient format for consumption by machines. In that case, dates should be ISO8601 and currency amounts, since they are decimals, should be sent in their numeric representation - not in a string one that is localised.

Comment: @DanPantry my friend I am not assuming anything, I had encountered these questions and at the end they said my system is lacking multilingual support so they have to use another service provider. AND It was not one or two clients but many of them asked same thing why your API cannot support our date format.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `[FromForm]`,you could create your own custom mobel binder for the `Price` property:

1.Create a `DecimalModelBinder`

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {

        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (valueProviderResult == null)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        // Replace commas and remove spaces
        value = value.Replace(",", ".").Trim();

        decimal myValue = 0;
        if (!decimal.TryParse(value, out myValue))
        {
            // Error
            bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(
                                    bindingContext.ModelName,
                                    "Could not parse MyValue.");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(myValue);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

2.Use it on `Price` property

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(BinderType = typeof(DecimalModelBinder))]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

3.Action

```
[HttpPost]
public Task<IActionResult> SaveProduct([FromForm]Product model){
  ....code to save the product....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting Decimal values for a price from the client is a terrible idea. I remember stories where a haphazard developer had put the shopping cart into the cookie, *including prices*. It took not that long for this mistake to be found and exploited. The company had the bill, because they had made their shop faulty.

Never trust input from the user. Especially if that user is on the Internet.

As for the specific problem: You basically have the issue that frontend and backend culture varies. I got 3 items of advice for transmitting numbers between processes:

- never transmit them as String. String is arguably the 2nd worst format for processing. The only thing worse is raw binary
- if you have to transmit them as string, make certain you pick fixed culture and encoding at both endpoints. Stuff like XML and JSON tends to take care of that for you. But you may have to pick something like the [Invariant Culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture).
- If you are transmitting, storing or retrieving a DateTime, always do so as UTC. And hope you do not have that rare application that has to store the original Timezone (like a calendar).

Comment: Well I made this for internet user right and we know what they can do. I had already tried your two mentioned methods now the only thing left is passing values as string and then convert them into decimal in API (not good idea).

Comment: "Getting Decimal values for a price from the client is a terrible idea." It sounds like OP is designing a system where a user can create a product and specify its price *by design*, so I think this isn't very useful advice.

Comment: @DanPantry Huh, never considered that option. But now that you said it, this finally makes sense. Well, the rest of my post still applies. I wish I had some knowledge of Angular to write some code. But I am only here because of the C# tag.

Comment: The rest of your answer is solid, though: 1. Do not transmit numbers as strings.. they are numbers. Strings should be opaque to the server in most cases. 2. You want to transmit date times in ISO8601 format - it doesn't much matter what the timezone the date/time is in as long as the timezone of the date/time is captured within the transmitted data. ISO8601 does this.